# Check if two nodes are directly connected in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I got stuck trying to find if 2 specific nodes are connected directly. I want to get `1` if the nodes are connected and `0` if they are not.

I wrote the following but it just finds all the neighbors.

```
MATCH (n WHERE ID(n)=1000)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {maxLevel: 1}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that you have two specific nodes, so I assume that you also know the other node.
I would solve this without APOC. Getting the Cypher basics without additional libraries first and find out later what you are missing, is -in my opinion- a better way to learn it.

Using the `CASE` expression might already do the job for you.

```
MATCH (a:A) RETURN CASE WHEN exists((a)-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]-(:B)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result
```

If you need to fetch both nodes more specific in the beginning:

```
MATCH (a:A{name:'abc'}) 
MATCH (b:B{name:'xyz'})
RETURN CASE WHEN exists((a)-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]-(:b)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result
```

also what fbiville said in his comment.

Comment: I think `WHERE (a)--(b)` would work too FYI.

Comment: `RETURN CASE WHEN (a)--(b) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS connected`

Comment: I agree with meistermeier - always try to use Cypher first, the best way to improve your understanding. Also, there is a performance price to pay calling Apoc procedures - small, but there.

fbivillle is correct too, but there is a small efficiency gain in using the relationship labels and direction if you know them.

You won't notice the above two points when working with a small graph, but it's possible you will when working with large graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
MATCH (n WHERE ID(n)=$node1)                                                                             
MATCH (m WHERE ID(m)=$node2)                                                                    
RETURN apoc.nodes.connected(n, m) AS output
```